# C# multilevel json array parsing

Tags: c#, json

I'm having some trouble parsing this JSON string. I can get it into a JObject or JArray just fine and even use JSON.NET's serialize method to get it into a dynamic object. The problem is that I need it to be in a model object rather than just some loose guess. The format for this specific JSON is always the same except for some entries a few nodes are missing.

The dynamic object I'm getting after parsing (from [the Path of Exile API](http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues)):

```
Type: Array
IsReadOnly: False
HasValues: True
First: {
  "id": "Standard",
  "description": "The default game mode.",
  "registerAt": null,
  "event": false,
  "url": "http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/71278",
  "startAt": "2013-01-23T21:00:00Z",
  "endAt": null,
  "rules": []
}
Last: {
  "id": "Aug 12 3h HC Race",
  "description": "A 3 hour HC race event with prizes. See the Beta Status forum for details.",
  "registerAt": null,
  "event": false,
  "url": null,
  "startAt": "2012-08-11T21:00:00Z",
  "endAt": "2012-08-12T00:00:00Z",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Hardcore",
      "description": "A character killed in Hardcore is moved to its parent league."
    }
  ]
}
Count: 50
Parent: 
Root: [
  {
    "id": "Standard",
    "description": "The default game mode.",
    "registerAt": null,
    "event": false,
    "url": "http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/71278",
    "startAt": "2013-01-23T21:00:00Z",
    "endAt": null,
    "rules": []
  },
 <- more stuff ->
  {
    "id": "Aug 12 3h HC Race",
    "description": "A 3 hour HC race event with prizes. See the Beta Status forum for details.",
    "registerAt": null,
    "event": false,
    "url": null,
    "startAt": "2012-08-11T21:00:00Z",
    "endAt": "2012-08-12T00:00:00Z",
    "rules": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Hardcore",
        "description": "A character killed in Hardcore is moved to its parent league."
      }
    ]
  }
]
Next: 
Previous: 
Path:
```

When I try to parse this into my model class it errors out when it finds the `rules` node. I tried defining rules as `List<String>`, custom `Rules` class (also still in but unused now) and `String[]`;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ExiledInfo.Objects
{   
    class LeagueWrapper : List<League>
    {
        public List<League> leagues;
    }
    class League
    {
        public String id;
        public String description;
        public String registerAt;
        public String @event;
        public String url;
        public String startAt;
        public String endAt;
        public List<String> rules;
    }
    class Rules : List<String>
    {
        public List<String> rules;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing/hoping that I'm missing something obvious.

The error I'm getting:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'rules[0]', line 1, position 255.
```

in code:

```
 Endpoint leagues = new Endpoint("http://api.pathofexile.com/leagues");

            String jsonString = API.makeRequest(leagues.getRequestURL());
            JArray data = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
            foreach (JObject item in data.Children())
            {
                League l = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<League>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
            }
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Handy tip for Visual studio: Copy your Json string into your clipboard then go into Visual Studio, `Edit` menu, `Paste Special` and select `Paste JSON As Classes`

Comment: Awesome, did not know that was possible!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this yesterday.  The issue is, your model is expecting a List of rules but since your rules are empty, it throws.  Even if there was 1 rule and not wrapped in [], it wouldn't know how to add that as a list.  This link breaks it down and resolved my issue.

http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/using-a-custom-jsonconverter-to-fix-bad-json-results/

Here is the code he uses in his tutorial:

```
    public class SingleValueArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            object retVal = new Object();
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));
                retVal = new List<T>() { instance };
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                retVal = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now decorate your list like

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SingleValueArrayConverter<List>))]
public List<String> rules;
```

Also use VisualStudio -> edit -> paste special -> paste json as classes.  This will created your classes for you based on the json you are consuming.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out and report on the results